# azure webapp for linux post deployment actions

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use the post deployment actions env variable with my windows webapps:
`SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH=D:\home\site\repository\azure\PostDeploymentActions`

and my `/azure/PostDeploymentActions/RestartWebjobs.cmd` file contains:

`php %HOME%\site\repository\artisan queue:restart`

Is there some equivalent for linux webapps?